# What is `$menuentry_id_option` in grub?

Tags: grub2

I was fiddling with my GRUB 2 config files (`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`) and I noticed that the `menuentry` line for the automatically added Ubuntu boot looks like this:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr (on sda5)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-fe3a2033-d77c-4d8c-ba04-3bb27b267dc2' {
```

What is that `$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-fe3a2033-d77c-4d8c-ba04-3bb27b267dc2'` part at the end and do I need it when I add new boot options?

So, what does the `$menuentry_id_option` mean?
Do I need to use it when I add another boot menu item for some other distro?
What would happen if I didn't include it?

Also, is there some GRUB reference I can look to for questions about what these things do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line you are looking for is:

```sh
if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi
```

Gives you the value of `feature_menuentry_id` and if it's equal to `y` then it will add the `--id` parameter to your menu entries:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr (on sda5)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --id 'gnulinux-simple-fe3a2033-d77c-4d8c-ba04-3bb27b267dc2' {
```

If it's not, then it will leave it as is:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr (on sda5)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os 'gnulinux-simple-fe3a2033-d77c-4d8c-ba04-3bb27b267dc2' {
```

The `--id` parameter for `menuentry` isn't defined in the manual for [`menuentry`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/menuentry.html#menuentry), but one can haphazardly guess is the UUID for the partition the kernel is supposed to boot from.

Comment: Ok.  I didn't catch the connection with the if statement.  I figured out the UUID part myself shortly after I asked the question.  Thanks, answer accepted.

Comment: Woah. Undocumented option and if we don't want to use it, we have a dangling optionless string on the command line? This is dirty...

Answer (score 3):

According to this mail:
https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/grub-devel/2013-01/msg00070.html

**excerpt**

> ```
> > @@ -3135,6 +3136,9 @@
> >  The @option{--hotkey} option associates a hotkey with a menu entry.
> >  @var{key} may be a single letter, or one of the aliases @samp{backspace},
> >  @samp{tab}, or @samp{delete}.
> > +
> > +The @option{--id} may be used to associate unique identifier with a menu entry. address@hidden is arbitrary string.
> ```
>
> It has to be [a-zA-Z_][0-9a-zA-Z_]* (while arbitrary string would work
>   it's not a good idea.

This option actually gives the menuentry a unique id, but is undocumented because it is not recommended. AFAIU, the partition UUID thing is merely a practice many distros follow in creating that id.

In Arch, for example, the format is "gnulinux-core repo kernel-true-{UUID}".

Comment: A wrinkle to this is that, because the `--id` option is both undocumented and (AFAICT) useless, distros don't always manage it quite correctly. For instance, Fedora's `grubby` boot-config-munger (which is run as part of every kernel package install, to edit `grub.cfg` directly, rather than using grub's `grub2-mkconfig` generator) just blindly copies the previous kernel's boot entry with some string-replacement on the kernel params. The result being that _every_ menuentry has the **exact same** "unique" ID specified for it.

Comment: (One unexpected feature of the Fedora menuid mismanagement I mentioned in my previous comment: Because the kernel version is encoded into the menuid when it's (properly) generated, you can get an idea of a Fedora install's age by looking at the menuid string that all of the menuentries are carrying around. For example, one of my home machines uses the menuid `gnulinux-4.12.11-200.fc25.x86_64-advanced-<UUID>` because I installed a new Fedora 25 root partition last year, as part of a primary hard drive upgrade.)